# React Router id as params

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an array called products. I got this array from the server and put it in apiAAddress. In a product called serviceService, there are two functions, one that receives the array and the other that receives the array with id. I am new to react so Maybe you can understand my problem

Service.jsx

```
import axios from "axios";
         
const apiAddress = 'http://localhost:5000/products';

export const productService = {
  getProducts: () =>{
    return axios.get(apiAddress)
  },

  getProductById: (id) => {
    return axios.get(apiAddress + id)

  }
};
```

In Detail, which is a class component, I also received data and id from productService.

Detail.jsx

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { productService } from "../components/cards/service";
    
class Detail extends Component {
        state = { } 
         
        componentDidMount() {
            const id =this.props.match.params.id;
            productService.getProductById(id).then(({data}) => this.setState({data}))
        }
        
    
        render() { 
            const data = this.state.data;
            if(!data)
            {
                return <div className="text-center mt-5">
                    Loading...
                </div>
            }
            return ( <>
            <div className="row">
                 <div className="col-5">
                     <img alt={data.title} src={data.src} width='100%' /> 
                 </div>
                 <div className="col-7">
                     <h1>{data.title}</h1>
                     <p>{data.text}</p>
                     <strong style={{color : 'green' , fontSize : 24}}>{data.price}</strong>
                 </div>
            </div>
            </> );
        }
    }

export default Detail;
```

I have some code here, but it does not work properly. I have tried all night long, but i cant find the error and It does not give me a mistake

App.jsx

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router , Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/navbar/navbar';
import Detail from './pages/detail';
import Home from './pages/home';

function App() {
  return ( 
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <div className='container m-3'>
       <Router>
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home />} /> 
            <Route path='/home' element={<Navigate replace to='/' />} />
           <Route path='/detail/:id' element={<Detail />} /> 
        </Routes>
      </Router>  
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CardItem is also related to products that go to the Detail component by clicking on show more.

CardItem.jsx

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";




const CardItem = ({data}) => {
    
    return ( <div className="card ml-5">
        <div className="card-body">
        <img alt={data.title} src={data.pic} className='card-img-top' />
        <h5 className='caard-title'>{data.title}</h5>
        <p style={{fontSize:22 , fontWeight: 700}} className="text-success">{data.price}</p>
        <Link to={'/detail/'+ data.id}> 
        <button className="btn btn-primary">Show More</button>
        </Link>
        </div>

    </div> );
}
 
export default CardItem;
```

Why is data not received in Detail?

Comment: "Does not work properly" isn't a useful description of the problem, you should show error messages, Chrome network-tab traces, ... Also can you explain what `axios.get(apiAddress + id)` is meant to achieve? Concatenating an id to `.../products` would result in a string like `.../products2123`.

Comment: It does not give me an error here at all. When I click on the detail button, the data of the desired page is loaded, but the data is not received.

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Fix the likely malformed URL for the request then check the response value, bot in the network tab and in your code.

Comment: The data in componentDidMount is not received in the Detail component and does not show anything

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at this line

```
return axios.get(apiAddress + id)
```

`apiAddress = 'http://localhost:5000/products'`, so if `id = '123'`, `apiAdress + id = 'http://localhost:5000/products123'`, which probably should be `'http://localhost:5000/products/123'`

Replace the first line with

```
return axios.get(apiAddress + '/' + id)
```

To avoid problems with the `/'s` you can also use the URL class

```
const productUrl = new URL(id, apiAdress).href;
return axios.get(productUrl);
```

You can read more about the URL class here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution but there was no problem with "/". The problem is that the data is not received correctly in the Detail component. Therefore, when I click on the details button, it goes to the relevant URL but the data is not displayed. Do you have a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data you are receiving the `id` from the params. When you send request using axios, you can get data from response like this:

```
productService.getProductById(id).then((response) => {
     this.setState({ data: response.data });
});
```

whereas you are setting the complete axios response object in state.

Second Issue:

```
const apiAddress = 'http://localhost:5000/products';
```

When you call `getProductById`, in axios.get when you concat `apiAddress` + `id`, it will looks like this: `http://localhost:5000/products1`. There should be a `/` after products. You should fix it by modifying getProductById.

```
return axios.get(`${apiAddress}/${id}`);
```

**TLDR: A better way to send requests & Handle Failed Requests**

In your productService you are not handling the failed requests.
You can create a single function that accepts an optional id and just return the data received from the response.

```
const sendRequest = async (id) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(apiAddress + (id ? `/${id}` : ''));
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        return {};
    }
};
```

You will set data like this:

```
sendRequest(id).then((data) => {
    this.setState({ data });
});
```